# Regular expression for pos. decimal integr that would be multiple of a number

Tags: regex, jflex

I am writing as ..

lets say we are finding a regexp of 7 then the multiple of 7 in reg exp would be [7|14|21|28]

does this seems resonable? please let me know..

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not evaluating mathematical values.

Answer (score 1):

`[7|14|21|28]` matches any character `7`, `|`, `1`, `4`, `2`, `8`.

To match `7` or `14` or `21` or `28`, you should use group (`(...)`) instead of set of characters (`[...]`):

```
(7|14|21|28)
```

Comment: when you say matches characters like 7, |, 1, 4, 2, 8 what do u mean? does [7|14|21|28] not mean that the expression is a multiple of 7 with 4 outputs?

also my aim is to find the regexp that will match for lets say multiple of number 7 .. 

what do you mean by use group?

Comment: @user3259486, `[...]` matches any character inside it. For example `[ABC]` matches `A` or `B` or `C`, not `ABC`.

Comment: But the reg exp that would match the multiple of 7 would have infinite number.. how would I write a exp that would fit in a [] bracket?

Comment: @user3259486, To get matches for multiple of 7. You'd better to match any numbers (`\d+`), and filter it using programming language. BTW, what programming language do you use?

Comment: @user3259486, `\d+` is equivalent to `[0-9]+`.

Comment: i am using jflex. I am still not understanding how this could result to the regex for the integer that would be a multiple of 7 ... I am sorry to ask but could you please give me a detailed knowledge of your understandings.

Comment: @user3259486, I don't know about jflex well. Here's [Python example](http://ideone.com/G5b9RF). I wish this help you.

Comment: I am actually looking for a regular expression match for a multiple of a positive dec. number(7 for example). I need how to find the regular exp.

Comment: @user3259486, Do you mean numbers that does not follow `-`? Then, try `[-\d]+` and filter out negative numbers afterward.

Comment: I dont have enough knowledge to understand your statement. what do you mean by follow -? and how can I use or try [-\d]+ ? Please be elaborative.

Comment: My aim is to find the regular expresion match of a positive decimal integer number 7.